# Modify the overlay tutorial issue

Tags: ros2, tutorial, ros-iron

Link: https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Creating-A-Workspace/Creating-A-Workspace.html#modify-the-overlay

I was going through the tutorial and it asked me to modify the turtle_frame.cpp.  I have done it Notepad++.  Unfortunately when it came to testing it out as per the instruction:

-Return to the first terminal where you ran colcon build earlier and run it again.

-Return to the second terminal (where the overlay is sourced) and run turtlesim again.

For some reason the name has not changed.

I'm new to this so I would like to see where I went wrong.

Comment: After editing in Notepad++ did you save the changes?

Comment: Yes I did save the changes.

Comment: Did you rerun the turtlesim node after saving the changes in the terminal where the overlay was sourced?